# Combinatoric question about four-digit numbers

Tags: combinatorics

You have a set of digits (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6). You need to find the amount of four-digit numbers such that they consist only of these digits and must contain at least one occurrence of 1, 2, and 3. Digits can repeat. We have `3*4*3!=72`numbers that consists 1 of 4,5,6 and 123 in some order. Can't understand though how to count numbers, that only consists of 1,2,3 with such condition.

Answer (score 1):

Number of combinations $=$ Total possible combinations ($6^4$) $−$ Combinations missing $1$ ($5^4$) $-$ Combinations missing $2$ ($5^4$) $−$ Combinations missing $3$ ($5^4$) $+$ Combinations missing $1$ and $2$ ($4^4$) + Combinations missing $1$ and $3$ ($4^4$) $+$ Combinations missing $2$ and $3$ ($4^4$) $-$ Combinations missing $1,2,3$ ($3^4$) $= 108$.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a permutation of a multiset, which are like normal sets except they can have multiple copies of one or more elements. Suppose you have a multiset $M$ such that $|M|=n$ for some natural number $n$, and that it contains elements $a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_m$ with multiplicities $k_1,k_2,k_3,...,k_m$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^{m}k_i=n$. Then the number of distinct permutations it is possible to make with these elements is equal to $\binom{n}{k_1,k_2,k_3,...,k_m}=\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!...k_m!}$

For example, suppose your multiset is $\{1,1,2,3\}$. Then $n$ is clearly $4$, $k_1=2$ (since there are $2$ copies of $1$), $k_2=1$ and $k_3=1$. Then the formula tells us that $\binom{4}{2,1,1}=\frac{4!}{2!1!1!}=\frac{24}{2}=12$. Thus, the number of unique $4$-digit numbers that can be made using $1,1,2,3$ is $12$.

Simply repeat this with other combinations which have multiples of one or more digits to get the total number of $4$-digit numbers that can be made with them.